# Ошибка matplotlib при отрисовке TeX текста

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, matplotlib, latex, tex

Следующий код используется для отображения LaTeX формул в Matplotlib:

```
def latex_draw(tex, ri, eq=False):
    '''
    :param tex:
    TeX code
    :param ri:
    random number for save
    :param eq:
    True or False, return size of img or not
    :return:
    if eq == True, then return size of img, else return nan
    '''
    print(tex)
    try:
        # Создание области отрисовки
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
        ax.set_axis_off()
        plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
        plt.rc('font', **{'family': 'verdana'})
        plt.rc('text.latex', unicode=True)
        plt.rc('text.latex', preamble='\\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}')
        plt.rc('text.latex', preamble='\\usepackage[russian]{babel}')
        # Отрисовка формулы
        plane_text = ax.text(0.5, 0.5, '$'+tex+'$', horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', fontsize=20,
                             color='black')

        # Определение размеров формулы
        ax.figure.canvas.draw()
        bbox = plane_text.get_window_extent()

        # Установка размеров области отрисовки
        fig.set_size_inches(bbox.width / 90, bbox.height / 60)  # dpi=100, но я сделал изображение побольше

        # Сохранение формулы в файл
        plt.savefig(path_home_dir + str(ri) + '_result.png')
        if eq:
            return fig.get_size_inches()*fig.dpi
        else:
            return
    except RuntimeError as error:   # Обработка исключения из-за ошибки в латексе. Если произошла ошибка из-за него,
                                # то алгоритм выполнится еще раз
        print(error.with_traceback(sys.exc_info()[2]))
        latex_draw(tex, ri)
        logging.error('Ошибка LaTeX')
    except Exception as error:
        print('Err', error.with_traceback(sys.exc_info()))
        latex_draw(tex, ri)
```

Раньше код выполнялся правильно, но сегодня почему-то стал выдавать ошибку при вводе в него следующего кода:

```
\\x_1=\left\{2 n \pi + \frac{5 \pi}{3}\; |\; n \in \mathbb{Z}\right\} \newline x_2= \left\{2 n \pi + \frac{\pi}{3}\; |\; n \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}\newline
```

P.S Двойные слеши - норма

Интересно то, что на другой машине этот код выполняется правильно и не приводит к ошибке.

ОС (обоих машин) Ubuntu 16.04, python 3.6, версии TeX пакетов (см ниже) совпадают, как и версии библиотек.

```
tex-common                  install
tex-gyre                    install
texlive-base                    install
texlive-binaries                install
texlive-extra-utils             install
texlive-font-utils              install
texlive-fonts-recommended           install
texlive-fonts-recommended-doc           install
texlive-generic-recommended         install
texlive-latex-base              install
texlive-latex-base-doc              install
texlive-latex-extra             install
texlive-latex-extra-doc             install
texlive-latex-recommended           install
texlive-latex-recommended-doc           install
texlive-pictures                install
texlive-pictures-doc                install
texlive-pstricks                install
texlive-pstricks-doc                install
```

Вот код из файла, который создаёт LaTeX:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6600) (preloaded format=latex 2018.3.16)  8 APR 2018 18:33
entering extended mode
**/root/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/49c5b48548c9ef93a64f5fc8c6968d0a.tex
(/root/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/49c5b48548c9ef93a64f5fc8c6968d0a.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 0 language(s) loaded.
(/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/type1cm/type1cm.sty
Package: type1cm 2002/09/05 v0.04 BlueSky/Y&Y Type1 CM font definitions (DPC, p
atched RF)
)
(/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package
Package textcomp Info: Sub-encoding information:
(textcomp)               5 = only ISO-Adobe without \textcurrency
(textcomp)               4 = 5 + \texteuro
(textcomp)               3 = 4 + \textohm
(textcomp)               2 = 3 + \textestimated + \textcurrency
(textcomp)               1 = TS1 - \textcircled - \t
(textcomp)               0 = TS1 (full)
(textcomp)             Font families with sub-encoding setting implement
(textcomp)             only a restricted character set as indicated.
(textcomp)             Family '?' is the default used for unknown fonts.
(textcomp)             See the documentation for details.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ? sub-encoding to TS1/1 on input line 79.

(/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \oldstylenums on input line 334.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 349.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 350.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 351.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 352.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmbr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 353.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 354.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ccr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 355.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptm sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 356.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pcr sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 357.
Package textcomp Info: Setting phv sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 358.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ppl sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 359.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pag sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 360.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pbk sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 361.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pnc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 362.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pzc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 363.
Package textcomp Info: Setting bch sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 364.
Package textcomp Info: Setting put sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 365.
Package textcomp Info: Setting uag sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 366.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ugq sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 367.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ul8 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 368.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ul9 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 369.
Package textcomp Info: Setting augie sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 370.
Package textcomp Info: Setting dayrom sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 371.
Package textcomp Info: Setting dayroms sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 372.

Package textcomp Info: Setting pxr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 373.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 374.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 375.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 376.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 377.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 378.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 379.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmdh sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 380.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 381.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmssq sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 382.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 383.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 384.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qhv sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 385.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qag sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 386.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qbk sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 387.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qcr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 388.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qcs sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 389.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qpl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 390.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qtm sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 391.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qzc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 392.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qhvc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 393.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futs sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 394.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 395.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 396.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlh sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 397.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hls sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 398.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlst sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 399.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlct sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 400.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlx sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 401.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlce sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 402.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcn sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 403.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcw sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 404.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcf sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 405.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pplx sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 406.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pplj sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 407.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 408.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 409.
)
(/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/ucs/ucs.sty
Package: ucs 2013/05/11 v2.2 UCS: Unicode input support

(/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/ucs/uni-global.def
File: uni-global.def 2013/05/13 UCS: Unicode global data
)
\uc@secondtry=\count87
\uc@combtoks=\toks14
\uc@combtoksb=\toks15
\uc@temptokena=\toks16
)
(/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks17
\inpenc@posthook=\toks18

(/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/ucs/utf8x.def
File: utf8x.def 2004/10/17 UCS: Input encoding UTF-8
))
(/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2018/02/14 3.18 The Babel package

(/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/babel/switch.def
File: switch.def 2018/02/14 3.18 Babel switching mechanism
)
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
(/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/arabi/bblopts.cfg
File: bblopts.cfg 2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of
 babel
)
(/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/babel-russian/russianb.ldf
Language: russian 2017/08/12 1.3j Russian support for the Babel system

(/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2018/02/14 3.18 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count88
\U@D=\dimen103

(/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
\bbl@dirlevel=\count89
)

Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel)                the language `Russian' into the format.
(babel)                Please, configure your TeX system to add them and
(babel)                rebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns
(babel)                preloaded for \language=0 instead on input line 28.

\l@russian = a dialect from \language0

Package babel Warning: No Cyrillic font encoding has been loaded so far.
(babel)                A font encoding should be declared before babel.
(babel)                Default `T2A' encoding will be loaded  on input line 74.


(/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2aenc.def
File: t2aenc.def 2005/09/27 v1.0i Cyrillic encoding definition file
)
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 120.
Package babel Info: Default for \cyrdash is provided on input line 157.
))
(/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry

(/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks19
)
(/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
(/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
(/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count90
\Gm@cntv=\count91
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count92
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen104
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen105
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen106
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen107
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen108
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen109
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen110
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen111
\Gm@dimlist=\toks20

(/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.cfg)

Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `h'-direction.
    `width' (5058.9pt) is ignored.


Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `v'-direction.
    `height' (5058.9pt) is ignored.

) (49c5b48548c9ef93a64f5fc8c6968d0a.aux)
\openout1 = `49c5b48548c9ef93a64f5fc8c6968d0a.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for TS1+cmr on input line 14.

(/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T2A/cmr/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T2A+cmr on input line 14.

(/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmr.fd
File: t2acmr.fd 2001/08/11 v1.0a Computer Modern Cyrillic font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.

(/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/ucs/ucsencs.def
File: ucsencs.def 2011/01/21 Fixes to fontencodings LGR, T3
)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: dvips
* paper: custom
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(72.26999pt, 5058.90001pt, 72.26999pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(72.26999pt, 5058.90001pt, 72.26999pt)
* \paperwidth=5203.43999pt
* \paperheight=5203.43999pt
* \textwidth=5058.90001pt
* \textheight=5058.90001pt
* \oddsidemargin=0.0pt
* \evensidemargin=0.0pt
* \topmargin=-37.0pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=65.0pt
* \marginparsep=11.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/cmr/m/n' in size <20> not available
(Font)              size <20.74> substituted on input line 15.

LaTeX Font Info:    Calculating math sizes for size <20> on input line 15.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.15 ... \pi + \frac{5 \pi}{3}\; |\; n \in \mathbb
                                                  {Z}\right\} \newline x_2= ...

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2506 strings out of 495224
 36079 string characters out of 3182009
 98795 words of memory out of 3000000
 5818 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 7520 words of font info for 24 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 0 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 24i,3n,32p,394b,101s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
No pages of output.
```

Вот полный код TeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{type1cm}



\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[papersize={72in,72in},body={70in,70in},margin={1in,1in}]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{20.000000}{25.000000}{\rmfamily $\\x_1=\left\{2 n \pi + \frac{5 \pi}{3}\; |\; n \in \mathbb{Z}\right\} \newline x_2= \left\{2 n \pi + \frac{\pi}{3}\; |\; n \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}\newline $}
\end{document}
```

Как мне это исправить?

Comment: Судя по ругательствам latex - проблема в команде `\mathbb`. Чтобы она работала надо добавить пакет `amsfonts`. А вот почему без нее работало раньше - не могу сказать. Скорее всего, кто-то неявно подгружал этот пакет...

Comment: @Vladimir а как мне подгрузить этот пакет?

Comment: как обычно: в самом latex -  в преамбуле (например, сразу после пакета `texcomp`) `\usepackage{amsfonts}`, а если в matplotlib, то как я понимаю по аналогии с остальными: `plt.rc('text.latex', preamble='\\usepackage{amsfonts}')`.

Comment: Хм, похоже, работает. Я сейчас всё перепроверю, но лучше напишите полный ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по выводу от latex, проблема в команде `\mathbb`. Чтобы она работала, надо добавить пакет `amsfonts`.
В latex нужно добавить в преамбуле (например, сразу после пакета textcomp) `\usepackage{amsfonts}`. В matplotlib, как я понимаю, по аналогии с остальными пакетами: `plt.rc('text.latex', preamble='\\usepackage{amsfonts}')`